# Turtlebot 3 e-manual - trouble contacting master

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I`m very new to programming, using Linux etc. But I have worked my way through the ROS programming book and am not working through the Turtlebot3 E-manual.

I am trying to bring up basic packages to start the Turtlebot 3 applications but am having an issue in contacting the master (my laptop).

- So I have run 'roscore'
- I then entered 'roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch' on my Turtbebot PC (Raspbian). But I cannot contact the master and am getting the error message:
  **ERROR: unable to contact ROS master at {http://my IP address is here}, The traceback for the exception was written to the log file"**".

I have done an extensive  search online for a solution and have found many discussions, but due to my inexperienced I am failing to see which solution suits my problem.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331360/turtlebot-3-e-manual---trouble-contacting-master/) by [jimc91](https://answers.ros.org/users/45049/jimc91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2019-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try assigning static ip to turtlebot and PC. then see if they can ping each other. On VM, instead of NAT, use bridge connection in network settings

---

Originally posted by [enthusiast.australia](https://answers.ros.org/users/43404/enthusiast.australia/) with karma: 91 on 2019-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0